# How to check azure storage availability through SDK or Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

In my application im trying to get the metrics of azure storage i.e metrics for each of its services(blob,queue,file,table) but before trying to get the metrics i want to check the availability of the storage ,can i do that please suggest.

i want to check if the storage status if its up or down before collecting metrics via SDK

Comment: Could you please explain more about the azure storage availability? Do you mean the SLA in the azure storage or the current storage status or the current storage usage?

Comment: @Brando Zhang i want to check if the storage status if its up or down before collecting metrics via SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could send the request to management.azure.com to get your storage account current status by using rest api.

The request is as below:

Get Method:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{yoursubscriptionsID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupname}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{Youraccount name}?api-version=2017-06-01
```

Request header:

```
authorization: Bearer {accesstoken}
```

More details about how to get the access token(Register your client application with Azure AD, Acquire an access token), you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/gettingstarted/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad).

Result:

Notice: it will return a json which contains all your storage account current message.

In this json message it contains the statusofPrimary property, this is the status.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to invoke the Metadata Rest API's for each of those storage services (blob, queue, table and file). You can go through below links to see the REST API specification that returns the metadata.

Storage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-and-retrieving-properties-and-metadata-for-blob-resources

Queue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-queue-metadata

Table - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-table-service-properties

File - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-directory-metadata